# Can't access MySQL views when moving the PHP application on another server

Tags: mysql, view

My current project is about doing some changes in an already build web application (PHP/MySQL). For displaying data, the previous developer used views. I got the app on my computer in order to get familiar with it and I can't seem to make those views work (I don't get any output in the app).

I searched the web for this an [there seems to be a problem](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16589) when you create a view with one database user and the that user no longer exists.

Anyone who got into this issue before? How can this be solved?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? What doesn't work? This is too hazy for a specific answer

Comment: I can't display that view in a PHP page.

Comment: "can't display that view" is a vague statement. What happens when you try? what does it say?

Comment: I don't get any error, I simply don't get any output from the database.

Comment: "Thank you for a problem report. Looks like it is intended behaviour since 5.0.16. The root
user should be able to change the view (including definer) with ALTER VIEW
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-view.html), or just by dropping and
creating it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're importing the views from SQL dump file, they are probably defined like this

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'userWhoDoesNotExist@thisServer' VIEW viewName AS ....
```

Try removing the `DEFINER =` part, and the view will be created using currenct user account.

Answer (score 1):

since you are running the server on your own computer, I am assuming you have root access. Try using something like

```
ALTER VIEW brokenView DEFINER='newuser'
```

this passes the validation check [here](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). As long as you are root when you do this, you should be able to recover your views.